# The process cannot access the file XXX because it is being used by another process in asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api, stream, content-disposition

I have developed ASP.NET web API. I am trying to read content of an excel file and trying to return it as bytes. I am getting following error:

```
The process cannot access the file 'C:\app\MyHost.AppServices\bin\Debug\temp\888.xlsx' because it is being used by another process.
```

I am using below code.I am not sure what is causing this error. Please provide your suggestions

```
public class FileController : MyBase
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)
        {


            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            var path = Path.Combine("temp", id);
            var fileStream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            //response.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);


            response.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite));
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = id;

            return response;

            }
    }
```

Comment: Your fileStream variable is not used and when creating StreamContent instance you create also new FileStream instance, that is not disposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never dispose the file from `var fileStream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);`, leaving it locked.

Comment: I have opened the file with the help of using block as well(which automatically calls dispose() ) but even that did not helped. I will try explicitly calling the dispose method

Comment: The line I pointed out seems to be unnecessary as you don't use `fileStream` later on (as you've commented out the use of it). I think it's safe to remove that line.

Comment: using `using` block is more sure way of disposing, than calling dispose manually - because it makes sure dispose is performed even if exception is thrown. On the other hand you can always use process explorer to see which process is locking your file.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Which line I should remove?

Comment: @Giedrius: Using process explorer makes lot of sense

Comment: The line I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Thank you for quick help. That extra line was causing the issue.